# android view animated background

Tags: android, video, background

Is there a way, to make view's background animated? Android cant handle animated GIFs in 1.5 afaik, and I can't set video for BG resource.

Comment: `Glide` supports GIFs. You can make a background an ImageView and set a Gif to it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps just lay your view over top of a videoview or your choice of view to handle the animation?